# ld: Undefined symbols error message during compilation

Tags: c++

I want to implement toy Database, which allows me to add, print, delete and find records in it. I have the following implementation of Database class:

**database.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;



class Database {
public:

    void Print(ostream& stream) const;
    void Add(const Date& date, std::string event);
    
    template<typename F>
    int RemoveIf(const F& lambda);
      
    template<typename F>
    std::vector<std::pair<Date,std::string>> FindIf(const F& lambda) const;
    
    std::tuple<Date, std::string> Last(const Date& date);

private:
    map<Date,std::vector<std::string>> db;
};



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename F>
    int Database::RemoveIf(const F& lambda){
        int deleted_elements = 0;
        for(auto &item : db){
            auto& date = item.first;
            auto& events = item.second;
            //auto to_remove = std::remove_if(events.begin(),events.end(), std::bind(lambda, std::placeholders::_1, std::cref(date)));
            auto to_remove = std::remove_if(events.begin(),events.end(), [&date, &lambda](const auto& event){ 
                return lambda(date,event);
                });
            events.erase(to_remove,events.end());
            deleted_elements += std::distance(to_remove, events.end());
        }

        return deleted_elements;
};


template<typename F>
std::vector<std::pair<Date,std::string>> Database::FindIf(const F& lambda) const{
    std::vector<std::pair<Date,std::string>> found_elements;
    for(auto &item : db){
        auto& date = item.first;
        auto& events = item.second;
        auto found_event_it = std::find_if(events.begin(),events.end(), [&date, &lambda](const auto& event){
            return lambda(date,event);
        });

        for (auto it = found_event_it; it != events.end(); ++it){
            found_elements.push_back(std::make_pair(date,*it));
        }

    }

    return found_elements;
};
```

**database.cpp**

```
#include "database.h"

using namespace std;

void Database::Print(ostream& stream) const{
    for (auto& elem: db){
        for(auto& event: elem.second){
            stream << elem.first << " " << event << std::endl;
        }
    }
    
};

void Database::Add(const Date& date, std::string event){
    if(db.count(date) == 0){
        db[date].push_back(event);
    } else{
        vector<string> v_events = db.at(date);

        auto it = std::find(v_events.begin(),v_events.end(),event);
        if(it != v_events.end()){
            db[date].push_back(event);
        }
    }
};



std::tuple<Date, std::string> Database::Last(const Date& date){
    auto latest_date_it = db.upper_bound(date);
    if(latest_date_it != db.end()){
        --latest_date_it;
        
        Date latest_date = latest_date_it->first;
        std::vector<std::string> latest_events = latest_date_it->second;

        std::string latest_event = latest_events.back();

        return std::make_tuple(latest_date,latest_event);

    } else{
        std::cout << "No Entries" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "database.h"
#include "date.h"
#include "condition_parser.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "test_runner.h"


using namespace std;


 
int main() {
    //TestAll();

    Database db;

    for (string line; getline(cin, line); ) {
        istringstream is(line);

        string command;
        is >> command;
        if (command == "Add") {
            const auto date = ParseDate(is);
            const auto event = ParseEvent(is);
            db.Add(date, event);

        } else if (command == "Print") {
            db.Print(cout);

        } else if (command == "Del") {
            auto condition = ParseCondition(is);
            auto predicate = [condition](const Date& date, const string& event) {
            return condition->Evaluate(date, event);
            };

            int count = db.RemoveIf(predicate);
            cout << "Removed " << count << " entries" << endl;
        
        } else if (command == "Find") {
            auto condition = ParseCondition(is);
            auto predicate = [condition](const Date& date, const string& event) {
            return condition->Evaluate(date, event);
            };

            const auto entries = db.FindIf(predicate);
            for (const auto& entry : entries) {
                cout << entry << endl;
            }
            cout << "Found " << entries.size() << " entries" << endl;
        } else if (command == "Last") {
             try {
                cout << db.Last(ParseDate(is)) << endl;
            } catch (invalid_argument&) {
                cout << "No entries" << endl;
            }
        } else if (command.empty()) {
        continue;
        } else {
        throw logic_error("Unknown command: " + command);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

During compilation linker throws me the following error:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  
  Database::Add(Date const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>), referenced from:
      _main in main-c6ce20.o
  Database::Last(Date const&), referenced from:
      _main in main-c6ce20.o
  Database::Print(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&) const, referenced from:
      _main in main-c6ce20.o

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I understand, that compiler doesn't see Database methods and I can't figure out why.

Comment: thats linker errors. How do you compile and link?

Comment: see also here https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/4117728 to understand why your code complies fine, but then fails to link